# Windows 8: Equivalent to [self.view addSubview:] (Obj-C)

Tags: c#, ios, windows, windows-8

Is there any known method on c# for the Windows 8 API that is Equivalent to

```
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

I need to add images to the view at a specific position but I cannot seem to find any method or function that'll let me do that.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what that method does, or perhaps what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Basically, I need to add a image on the page that is being displayed, but I need to be able to move it.